# Increment a number once each time a function is ran in Powershell 5.0

Tags: powershell, loops, increment, auto-increment

I'm just looking for a way to increment the variable $Num each time the script below it is ran.  So the script starts by using 168, runs, then increments to 169, runs again, etc. up until 999.  Thanks!

```
$Path = "H:\ClientFiles\CHS\Processed\"
$Num = 168
$ZipFile = "FileGroup0000000$Num.zip"
$File = "*$Num*.83*"
$n = dir -Path $Path$File | Measure

        if($n.count -gt 0){
        Remove-Item $Path$ZipFile
        Compress-Archive -Path $Path$File -DestinationPath $Path
        Rename-Item $Path'.zip' $Path'FileGroup0000000'$Num'.zip'          
        Remove-Item $Path$File            

        }    
        else {
            Write-Output "No Files to Move for FileGroup$File"
        }
```

Comment: If it run on the same machine each time why not store the $num value in the registry then check it is not Greater the 999 and update it each time the script runs

Comment: you can't do it in code, because script can't change his own code(you must create script that runs script and then change script file). Every time you run it, variable initialization begins and it always be 168 at start. But you can store it in file and read from file it.

Comment: Do you want to increment every time the script is run, or just once for every time it finds a file

Comment: @Scepticalist I want it to increment every time the script is run.  This is because there are only two outcomes in my case, either the directory has files to compress, or it doesn't (hence the else statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is essentially what `for` loops are for!

```
$Path = "H:\ClientFiles\CHS\Processed\"
for($Num = 168; $Num -le 999; $Num++){
    $ZipFile = "FileGroup0000000$Num.zip"
    $File = "*$Num*.83*"
    $n = dir -Path $Path$File | Measure

    if ($n.count -gt 0) {
        Remove-Item $Path$ZipFile
        Compress-Archive -Path $Path$File -DestinationPath $Path
        Rename-Item "${Path}.zip" "${Path}FileGroup0000000${Num}.zip"
        Remove-Item $Path$File

    }
    else {
        Write-Output "No Files to Move for FileGroup$File"
    }
}
```

Breakdown of our `for()` loop declaration:

```
for($Num = 168; $Num -le 999; $Num++){
 #       ^            ^          ^
 #       |            |          | Increase by one every time
 #       |            | Keep running as long as $num is less than or equal to 999
 #       | Start with an initial value of 168
}
```

Comment: For some reason, this loop doesn't work though.  When I put in individual values, the process runs as expected.  But with this for loop, the script runs and says complete without doing anything.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure you want to go this route.  You can have a module that maintains a script variable:

```
# file.psm1

$script:num = 1

function myfunc {
  $script:num
  $script:num++
}
```

```
import-module .\file.psm1

myfunc
1

myfunc
2

myfunc
3

remove-module file
```

I am answering the title of the post.  The module for you would look like this, but the powershell prompt would have to always be open.

```
$num = $script:Num = 168

function myfunc { 
  $Path = ".\"
  $ZipFile = "FileGroup0000000$Num.zip"
  $File = "*$Num*.83*"
  $n = dir -Path $Path$File | Measure

  if($n.count -gt 0){
    Remove-Item $Path$ZipFile
    Compress-Archive -Path $Path$File -DestinationPath $Path
    Rename-Item $Path'.zip' $Path'FileGroup0000000'$Num'.zip'          
    Remove-Item $Path$File            
  } else {
    Write-Output "No Files to Move for FileGroup$File"
  }

  $script:num++
}
```

Comment: This doesn't generate a loop though.  I get where you're coming from but I'm not getting how I would fit this into my script efficiently